# IOS: access to local network

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'am creating an app for IOS. For this app i need access to the local network. Is there a code or something i can add to the info.plist.xml that ask for the permission when my app starts? it need to aks for permission to access the local network so the app can search for other devices on that network.

Comment: It already has access to the local network. You'll need to be more specific about the "search for other devices" part, i.e. there could be any number of services that they might advertise

Comment: @DaveNottage i solved the problem. i was connected with the local test server. when i connected with the right server the message was gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you connect to the local server this message will show up. When I connected to the server where my service is running for the customer, the message will not be shown.